# flexslider cant adjust height

Tags: javascript

I have installed Flexslider on my site (just locally on PC at the moment), it adjusts the width of the slide fine when I reduce the size of the screen width using the browser, but the height of the slide always stays the same and the image appears crushed when the browser is at minimum width. Can anyone help please? I have tried going through all the youtube videos etc.. but cant see what I'm doing wrong. I am using the Omega 3 theme if thats relevant.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I run into this when using Omega 4.  What I do is set my base img tag to have an auto height:

```
img {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thats fixed it , many thanks , i added this to global.css in my omega theme css folder (the same problem occurs for any theme) :
.flexslider .slides img {
height:auto;
}

Answer (score 0):

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    .comp{
        font-size: small;
        width: 184%;
    }
    .img-responsive{
        height:auto;
    }
    .slider{
        height:auto;
    }

}

add class="comp" to each image and try